# Why do we need the address location of (&) when scaning input in C

Tags: c, variables, reference

I'm just going over some C notes and I was wondering if you was to do this:

```
int var1 = 0;
scanf("%d", var1);
```

You would encounter some sort of problem. Where as if you wrote it with the address location of operation as so:

```
int var1 = 0;
scanf("%d", &var1);
```

It works perfectly fine.

I've always been under the impression that to store a value you use just the variable name...why are we specifying the address lcoation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because C copies parameters by value. Consider this (useless) function:

```
void set_one(int x)
{
    x = 1;
}
```

When you call this as

```
int i = 2;
set_one(i);
```

That's the same as

```
set_one(2);
```

The function gets a copy of the `2`, calls it `x`, then overwrites it with a `1` and returns. The original `2`, aka `i`, is not changed.

To make this function even remotely useful, you must tell it *where* to put its result, instead of the current *value in* the result location:

```
void set_one(int *p)
{
    *p = 1;
}
```

Now a call `set_one(&i)` tells the function to store it's result at the place designated by the variable name `i`, which gets overwritten as a result.

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf` function needs to know where `var1` is stored in memory in order to modify it. If you pass just `var1` to `scanf`, then only  value of `var1` gets pushed onto the stack. You need to pass `&var1` so that the *address* of `var1` gets pushed onto the stack. Once you've done that, then `scanf` can dereference the pointer to modify the variable in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

> why are we specifying the address lcoation?

Because compiler don't know where to store the value and that's why it needs an address of variable to store value rather than the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default parameter passing in C is to pass the parameters by value.  When you specify the address, the contents pointed to by the address get modified by the function and that is visible in the calling function.